# preg_match All SRC tag of a web page

Tags: php, regex

Can any one provide me regex for finding all src tag. I am stuck for last two hours sometimes scripting works some times img but i want regular expression for all.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: [One doesn't simply use regex to parse HTML.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) PHP has a DOM parser so use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$pattern = '~<[^>]*?src="([^"]+)"[^>]*>~i';
```

This should match any tag having `src` attribute.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @AjayKadyan Changed now...this will be case insensitive.

Comment: Will you post your code...need to see the context in which you are using it. Without that, nobody here will be of much help to you.

Comment: See my post now. It will return all `href` values in an array. You can do an `implode` to get a string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use,

```
$html = file_get_contents("http://www.example.com");
preg_match_all ( '@src="([^"]+)"@' , $html , $match );
var_dump($match);
```

**EDIT**

To be more specific, and get all values for src and SRC in single quote or double quote

```
preg_match_all ( '@src=([\'"])(.*)([\'"])@' , $html , $match );
preg_match_all ( '@SRC=([\'"])(.*)([\'"])@' , $html , $match2 );
var_dump($match);
var_dump($match2);
```

Comment: Again use preg_match_all function for "SRC" and store it's elements in $match2. So now you have two array $match and $match2. Mix both of them and you have complete list of src.